# The magic of DUAL

Tags: oracle, dual-table

Under normal conditions (not using `SYS` or maybe using it)-

```
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X
```

Under not so normal conditions (connected as `SYS`)-

```
SQL> alter database close;
Statement processed.

SQL> select * from dual;
ADDR     INDX       INST_ID    D
-------- ---------- ---------- -
00FA6E50          0          1 X
```

I know `DUAL` is a special magic table (etc. etc.) but

What is different with `DUAL` when the DB is on standby? What is the relevance if `ADDR`, `INDX`, `INST_ID` in standby?

Comment: Better asked on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, I am not sure if a DBA would know the relevance of these columns or a programmer would!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom Kyte did an excellent job answering this question quite a few years ago, here:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have seen this post but I don't see where he explained the columns `ADDR`,`INDX`, `INST_ID` and their relevance, and why these column would only show up on DB Standby. I guess its just one of the things in Oracle's "black box".

Comment: Those are all standard columns in any X$ table.  ADDR is the address, literally, the memory address where that particular row is mapped in the SGA.  INST_ID is the instance id.  For single instance (non-RAC) databases, it's always 1.  For RAC databases, it varies from 1 to n, where n is the number of nodes in the RAC cluster.  And INDX, I think is an internal array that indexes all the X$ tables.  So, if there are n X$ tables in the system, each X$ will have a unique value, from 1 to n.